# Simple slideshow for MVC 4 Razor website

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've just started my FIRST ever (sorry if this is a very basic question) MVC app by selecting new MVC 4 Razor app in VS 2012.

In the Home\Index.cshtml I need a slideshow of 5 images. Only limited functionality required and so it looks like [snook.ca example](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) should work fine.

I've added my images as follows:

```
<div class="fadein">
            <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/1.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
            <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/2.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
            <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/3.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
            <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/4.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
            <img src="~/Content/img/old_photos/5.jpg" alt="Old Photos" />
        </div>
```

In the site.css page I have added the following:

```
.fadein { position:relative; width:300px; height:300px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
```

At the bottom of the Index.cshtml page (after the `</ol>`, I have added the following:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
           .next('img').fadeIn()
           .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    },
      3000);
});
</script>
```

When I run the app, all of the images are displayed at the same time - spread all over the page flowing one after the other. It seems that the function is not being execute. My question is how do I get it to run?

Comment: This seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/wGEpR/ . Is there any js error on your browser console?

Comment: Yes, the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" against the line: "$(function () {" just after the opening script tag. What does this mean please?